# Newly added jobs not running in cron.daily

Tags: cron, cron-task

I'm trying to add a daily cron job to backup a database. I'm able to do it manually by running `sh /path/to/file/backup.sh` but when I place the file in the cron.daily directory, it doesn't run daily. To try and diagnose it, I created a test file in cron.daily called test just to see if it would run. When I ran `run-parts --test /etc/cron.daily`, I got the output

`/etc/cron.daily/apache2`

`/etc/cron.daily/apt`

`/etc/cron.daily/bsdmainutils`

`/etc/cron.daily/dpkg`

`/etc/cron.daily/etckeeper`

`/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`, etc.

So then I tried copying the content of logrotate to a new file, atest, then ran run-parts again but with the same results.

atest:

```
#!/bin/sh

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
```

**Is there something special I need to do to get cron to recognize a newly added task in cron.daily?**

This isn't unique to cron.daily, I've tried monthy, weekly, and hourly as well with the same results. I've also tried restarting cron without success. I'm running this on Debian 7.2.

Comment: Do the permissions of your new file match the permissions of the other files (0644)?

Comment: @BradBales welp that appeared to do the trick. I changed the permissions of the file to match the others and I ran the cron.daily with `run-parts` and they all ran. Thanks a boatload, mate. If you can formulate an answer out of that I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, @notblakshelton!  The last time I wrestled with cron I had a dot in the filename, and couldn't figure out why it wasn't running:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that can keep files within your /etc/cron* directories from running (e.g. /etc/cron.daily):

1. Permissions.  Make sure the permissions of the files are 0644.
2. The filename must meet certain conditions.  From the documentation: "...they must be entirely made up of letters, digits and can only contain the special signs, underscores ('_') and hyphens ('-').  Any  file  that  does not conform to these requirements will not be executed by run-parts.